# Can't login to my user account in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 12.10

Hi I have problem to accesses to my account I'm installed Ubuntu in virtual box(oracle) and after this install I tried to log in and it just think and then go back to the screen of LogIn what should I do?

Comment: There are many questions on this site and many threads on forums about this. Unfortunately, it's caused by a _lot_ of things, and there's no one fix. Since it's in a virtual machine, I'm assuming you don't have much data. A reinstall is honestly the best option in this case.

Comment: I am already tried to reinstall this and its doesn't work.

Comment: A clean reinstall still doesn't allow you to to log in? I clean reinstall is erasing your VM or your VM's hard drive and reinstalling Ubuntu. This is what you did?

Comment: wait how did I do that? how do I cleaning this? pls step by step I am new in this Linux system

Comment: If you don't have any important data on the VM, just delete it in VirtualBox and create a new one.

Comment: you mean that I need to remove this and trying to install this over again?

Comment: and if so...how you install maybe I am doing the install wrong you can tell how to install this?

Comment: Wait, you can't log in directly after the installation?

Comment: yes in did I am stack in the session I tried the guest session also and this is also doesn't work

Comment: you're in Windows right? Try using VMWare instead.

Comment: why you thing this is the problem that I have windows and this virtual box that not work with this?

Comment: I've found people have problems with VirtualBox. VMWare is generally more stable to use for virtual machines.

Comment: ok right now I will install this machine and try again I will be in contact with you. Thanks men

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue last night!

1) Enter the terminal (CTRL + ALT + F1)

2) Login with your username & password

3) `sudo rm .Xauthority`

4) `sudo shutdown -r now`

Comment: tried doesn't work also...

Comment: @sfen - Hold on, you tried a clean re-install and it still doesn't work?

Comment: yes I don't understand what go wrong